# How to stop a Java process running in a webserver

Tags: java, multithreading, java-ee-6

How can I stop/cancel a process triggered through a button click?
My request goes through Servlet and finally invokes a method of my service class.
Is there any way I can stop the method execution after a certain time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box solution available for this but this can easily be implemented. You can fire a monitor thread on method call which can monitor the timing and either kill the process or notify some other method.

You can of course implement logic in a several ways from here.

Comment: The need is providing privilege to user to kill the process if he wish otherwise not, probably through a button click.Is it possible.